# evaluating objects inside gather function, tidyr, R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I am writing a function which uses gather to convert from wide to long format data frames. Here is an example of what I want to do:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

###simulated data
z0 <- data.frame(id = 1:10, 
                 A.pre = rnorm(10), 
                 B.pre = rnorm(10), 
                 A.Post = rnorm(10), 
                 B.Post = rnorm(10))

####data.frame with info about variables in z0
choix <- data.frame(var = colnames(z0), 
                    pairs = c(NA, "A", "B", "A", "B"), 
                    stringsAsFactors = F)

i <- "A"

z0 %>% 
    select(c("id", choix[choix$pairs %in% i, 1] )) %>%
    gather(time, i, choix[choix$pairs %in% i, 1])
```

The idea is to obtain a long format data frame with variables `id`, `time` and `A`, the character stored in object `i`. However, the names of the data frame obtained are `id`, `time`, `i`. How to make gather to evaluate  object `i` and use its contents?

Comment: Sorry, I wont do it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just unquote the variable value in the expression

```
z0 %>% 
  select(c("id", choix[choix$pairs %in% i,1] )) %>%
  gather(time,!!i,choix[choix$pairs %in% i,1]
```